# How to set a file to the definition of the valuable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have such a problem. I created a Character class. Also I created an ".asset" file and called it "Alice". I try to run a code:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Character", menuName = "Character data", order = 51)]
public class Character : ScriptableObject {
    [SerializeField]
    public new string name;
    [SerializeField]
    public Color color;
}

public class TextPrinting : MonoBehaviour {

     public Text nameText;
     public Character Alice;

     void say (Character ingamecharacter) {
         nameText.text = ingamecharacter.name;
         nameText.color = ingamecharacter.color;
     }

     void Start() {
         say(Alice);
     }
}
```

But I have a NullReferenceException error on 15 line. I wrote a definition for nameText.

```
nameText = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Panel/NamePanel/NameText").GetComponent<Text>();
```

But I still have this error. So (I guess) the problem is that I need to write a definition for Alice Character. But I don't understand how can I do this if it's a Scriptable Object and I need to use file from Assets folder to do this.

What should I do? Or I do totally wrong thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Which line is line 15?

Comment: @Sach nameText.text = ingamecharacter.name;

Comment: Also, you pass `Alice` to the `say()` method, but where do you instantiate it?

Comment: Is `Alice` referenced in the Inspector?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, it is.

Comment: @Sach In inspector, but it doesn't work

Comment: Well it's hard to answer here without seeing all relevant code. The error is pretty self explanatory, your `Alice` isn't instantiated, hence it can't find `ingamecharacter.name`.

Comment: is `nameText` referenced in the Inspector? or where do you call the `Find("...")`? Does exactly that object have a `Text` component or is it maybe somewhere in the children?

Comment: @Sach could also be the `nameText` but yes you are right ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @derHugo true, I assumed that he verified the `Find()` works.

Comment: @derHugo I tried both referencing in Inspector and by Find(...), it both works in Unity but when I build this game it doesn't work

Comment: soooo this is about a Build ... that's an information that should be in your question!

Comment: @derHugo oh god sorry, my bad

Comment: @derHugo need to say that I have this mistake in Unity too but in Unity everything works nice. And in Build it doesn't work

Comment: @derHugo so do you have any idea what can it be now?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

Make Character a Monobehaviour:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour {
    public string name;
    public Color color;
}
```

Change the Alice variable to a GameObject, and add code to get the Character component from it:

```
public class TextPrinting : MonoBehaviour {

     public Text nameText;
     public GameObject Alice;

     void say (Character ingamecharacter) {
         nameText.text = ingamecharacter.name;
         nameText.color = ingamecharacter.color;
     }

     void Start() {
         say(Alice.GetComponent<Character>());
     }
}
```

Then, create an empty GameObject and put a Character component on it and you can define it how you'd like Alice to be.

Then save that GameObject as a prefab called "Alice".

Then drag the Alice prefab to the "Alice" field in your TextPrinting component.

Comment: It's an idea but I have a large peace of code (I posted a shortened version of it). But thanks!

Comment: And if I want to use a `ScriptableObject`? Suggesting to use a prefab instead is a bit strange since `ScriptableObject`s are usually used for different stuff

Comment: @derHugo yea, it's better for me to use Scriptable Object but I have such a mistake(

Comment: @derHugo I saw they were creating .asset files that seemed not to be changed at run time so it seemed like they didn't actually need any serializing in that class.

Comment: @Ruzihm oh, I really don't change this files. Aaaaaand I use serialization only because the guy who explained me what is Scriptable Object said that I should use it